# Are there any new tricks for auto playing embedded YouTube videos inside an Android WebView?

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview

I've read lots of posts but none of the old tricks, like `autoplay` or `playsinline` or `allow='autoplay'` work.

I have full control over the `WebView` so I've even tried `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture` set to `false` but it didn't help.

Any other tricks?

This is how I load the `iframe`:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" allow="autoplay" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/${YOUTUBE_VIDE)_ID}?autoplay=1&playsinline=1" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a combination of the steps from this page https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference and `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture` will allow me to auto play the video. Even tested it on the newest Android System WebView on Android 12.